# Service Bean unsatisfied dependency when testing with DataJpaTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, junit5

I am trying to use Spring Boot test using the JUnit 5 & AssertJ for the first time using DataJpaTest with the help of H2 Database in-memory data.

I created a simple Person entity:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PersonID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "FirstName", length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LastName", length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "BirthDate")
    private LocalDate birthDate;
}
```

With a PersonRepository:

```java
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
}
```

And then a Service and its implementation:

```java
public interface PersonService {
    public List<Person> getAll();
}
```

Impl:

```java
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{

    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PersonServiceImpl(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public List<Person> getAll() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
```

And then I already input a data from database

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "Testing",
        "birthDate": "2001-01-01"
    }
]
```

When I tried testing it at the controller (manually) it received no problem. What I wanted to try out is to create a at the test/resources/application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2://mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create-drop
```

Then at the test/java/package/PersonServiceTest, I tried to test using @DataJpaTest:

```java
@DataJpaTest
class PersonServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @Test
    void getAll() {
        assertThat(personService.getAll()).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

It failed with the following error:

```
Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration



2022-01-07 11:33:49.415 ERROR 1564 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3e84448c] to prepare test instance [com.indocyber.springdata.service.PersonServiceTest@2ed2d9cb]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.indocyber.springdata.service.PersonServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.indocyber.springdata.service.PersonService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:417) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119) ~[spring-test-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248) ~[spring-test-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) [spring-test-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:313) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.indocyber.springdata.service.PersonService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
```

So far,

- I tried to test the Repository and it worked fine,
- I tried using the service, it always returns this error and telling me that the service can't find the Bean.
- I also tried the ServiceImpl directly to only find the same error.

I've been trying to figure out this one for hours, I'm clueless to why it doesn't respond to the Auto Configuration of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider changing the `@DataJpaTest` with 2 other annotations the `@SpringBootTest` with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`.

If you inspect the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) describing `@DataJpaTest` you can see that this annotation switches of auto configuration and does not bring the complete application context up as you would normally expect when the application loads.

This annotation is used so that spring creates everything necessary just for JPA layer (meaning your repository), so that the JPA layer can be tested.

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead
> apply only configuration relevant to JPA tests.

It is also adviced from the java doc that

> If you are looking to load your full application configuration, but
> use an embedded database, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined
> with @AutoConfigureTestDatabase rather than this annotation.

Comment: It worked!
I actually followed a tutorial from youtube hence I didn't know much about @DataJpaTest I thought its just a regular autowiring component. 

Thank you for the solution and the clear explanation. :)